# How to change gazebo plugin parameter

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. When I spawn create base turtlebot, turtlebot begins to navigate on its own. I suspect that in file `create_gazebo.urdf.xacro` under `create_description` package like in this code snippet **alwaysOn** parameter is causing this. Is there any way to change value of this parameter in launch file or only way is changing this file ?

```
....
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="turtlebot_gazebo">
<xacro:macro name="sim_create">
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="create_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_create.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <node_namespace>turtlebot_node</node_namespace>
      <left_wheel_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_wheel_joint>
      <right_wheel_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_wheel_joint>
      <front_castor_joint>front_castor_joint</front_castor_joint>
      <rear_castor_joint>rear_castor_joint</rear_castor_joint>
      <wheel_separation>.260</wheel_separation>
      <wheel_diameter>0.066</wheel_diameter>
      <base_geom>base_footprint_collision_base_link</base_geom>
      <updateRate>40</updateRate>
      <torque>1.0</torque>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
.....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193759/how-to-change-gazebo-plugin-parameter/) by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is specifying that the plugin controller is always on. That is not causing your robot to begin to navigate. It is just allowing it to react. Without the controller running the plugin would not respond to commands, or properly update state.

It's not parameterized because it's not designed to be able to be turned on or off. You need to find what is sending cmd_vel to your (virtual) robot and disable that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1